# How to ignore table and its content while extracting text from pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pdfplumber

So far I am successful extracting the text content from a pdf file. I am stuck to a point where i have to extract text content outside of the table (ignore table and its content) and need help

The Pdf can be downloaded from [here](https://www.iras.gov.sg//irashome/uploadedFiles/IRASHome/Quick_Links/International_Tax/List%20of%20Reportable%20Jurisdictions%20for%202020%20CRS%20information%20reporting_9%20Feb.pdf)

```
import pdfplumber
pdfinstance = pdfplumber.open(r'\List of Reportable Jurisdictions for 2020 CRS information reporting_9 Feb.pdf')

for epage in range(len(pdfinstance.pages)):
    page = pdfinstance.pages[epage]
    text = page.extract_text(x_tolerance=3, y_tolerance=3)
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the PDF you have shared, you can use the following code to extract the text outside the tables

```py
import pdfplumber


def not_within_bboxes(obj):
    """Check if the object is in any of the table's bbox."""

    def obj_in_bbox(_bbox):
        """See https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/blob/stable/pdfplumber/table.py#L404"""
        v_mid = (obj["top"] + obj["bottom"]) / 2
        h_mid = (obj["x0"] + obj["x1"]) / 2
        x0, top, x1, bottom = _bbox
        return (h_mid >= x0) and (h_mid < x1) and (v_mid >= top) and (v_mid < bottom)

    return not any(obj_in_bbox(__bbox) for __bbox in bboxes)


with pdfplumber.open("file.pdf") as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        print("\n\n\n\n\nAll text:")
        print(page.extract_text())

        # Get the bounding boxes of the tables on the page.
        bboxes = [
            table.bbox
            for table in page.find_tables(
                table_settings={
                    "vertical_strategy": "explicit",
                    "horizontal_strategy": "explicit",
                    "explicit_vertical_lines": page.curves + page.edges,
                    "explicit_horizontal_lines": page.curves + page.edges,
                }
            )
        ]

        print("\n\n\n\n\nText outside the tables:")
        print(page.filter(not_within_bboxes).extract_text())
```

I am using the `.filter()` method provided by `pdfplumber` to drop any objects that fall inside the bounding box of any of the tables (in `not_within_bboxes(...)`) and creating a filtered version of the page which will only contain those objects that fall outside any of the tables.